# How to populate the found in drop down in bug in azure board

Tags: azure, kanban, azure-boards

I have created a pipeline in azure portal it has created a build no having xxx now when I am raising a bug in azure board there is a drop down named as found in it is populating to none while I am expecting it to populate to xxx.
Work item element needs to be changed